# spark from my local windows machine to cloudera cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a cloudera CDH cluster running,but i want to submit jobs from my windows machine.

I have done all copying of configuration files from cluster to windows machine and install a local copy of spark ( spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz file from spark downloads page). I am able to run simple wordcount application with yarn but when i tried to connect to hive metastore it is showing lots of error ( i have copied hive-site.xml into spark/conf )

1) Is the pre-built spark distribution from spark downloads doesn't come with hive support

2) If not then i have to manually built it? (there is no place where i can download this required pre-built spark)

Please help (stuck on this like for 2 weeks)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your mean your wordcount program worked on cloudera yarn cluster right? not on your local

Comment: yes, wordcount program run on cloudera yarn cluster from this command:
spark-submit --class class --master yarn wordcount.jar words.txt,
And words.txt is on hdfs on cloudera

Answer (score 0):

Use hivecontext to access hive

```
@transient private var instance: HiveContext = _
def getHiveContext(sparkContext: SparkContext): HiveContext = {
    synchronized {
      if (instance == null) {

        println("creating hive context")
        System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://server-ip:9083")
        instance = new HiveContext(sparkContext)

      }
      instance
    }
```

Comment: What about hive-site.xml? I have to include it somewhere or just left it

Comment: Your spark program will use cluster hive so you don't need to add hive-site.xml on local spark. Local Spark is only used for submitting jar on yarn. There is no other use of local spark.